# Do all smooth, differentiable manifolds have an acceleration field?

Tags: differential-geometry, acceleration, vector-fields

I made the claim on a manuscript that all manifolds possess an acceleration field. The referee rejected the idea saying *"The nature of this acceleration field has not been seriously discussed and the theory lacks justification in physics"*. This confused me as I understand that a field, in physics, is

> a region of space for which each point is associated with a specific physical quantity.

Velocity is a physical quantity. If we impose an evolution parameter, then don't all points on this manifold have a velocity (vector) quantity? Is that not sufficient to claim the manifold has a velocity field?

Can we not also take the second derivative of the position with respect to our evolution parameter and say that every point on a manifold has an acceleration (vector) quantity? Does that not also qualify as a field?

Is there an argument to be made that all smooth, differentiable manifolds do not possess an acceleration field?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to say? For example, if your manifold is $\mathbb R$, what is the acceleration field?

Comment: I'm not sure why my manifold would be the set of real numbers. I would think of an arbitrary curve on the manifold as $\gamma\colon\mathbb{R}\to M$. Then the velocity would be $\dot\gamma (\tau)$. The acceleration field would then be $A^{\alpha}=(\nabla_{\dot\gamma}\dot\gamma)^{\alpha}$ which should expand to:$$A^\alpha=\Gamma^\alpha _{\mu\nu }u^{\mu}u^{\nu}+\frac{du^{\alpha }}{d\tau }$$

Comment: @TheShepard - But this equation is the acceleration of a particle moving along velocity field. What about a particle that is being pushed in some other direction (say, by a rocket engine). This gives a different velocity and acceleration, with the localized acceleration not corresponding to any field. You are implicitly assuming derivatives along passive particle trajectories, a perhaps natural idea but actually requiring definition in a paper.

Comment: [Duplicate title on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4799300/do-all-smooth-differentiable-manifolds-have-an-acceleration-field)

Comment: A [somewhat similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4642518/568204) was asked a while back where again that OP wanted some sort of *‘acceleration vector field’* whatever that’s supposed to mean. My answer there is again the same (as people above and in the above link have been trying to say): there is no such intrinsic notion.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149535/discussion-on-question-by-the-shepard-do-all-smooth-differentiable-manifolds-ha); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the referee. There is not a concept of an acceleration field in a standard pseudo-Lorentzian manifold that is well known in the literature and it seems to be a highly problematic concept.

Acceleration is a property of timelike curves in the manifold, not a property of the manifold itself. Through any event in the manifold there are an infinite number of timelike curves, each of which may in general have a different acceleration. So it does not associate each event in the manifold with a specific physical quantity. Rather, the physical quantity of acceleration is associated each event on a curve.

A field is a mapping from events on the manifold to some tensor. Not a mapping from events on a curve to some tensor. The “domain” is wrong. If I were the reviewer I would have made a similar objection.

Also, in general relativity the only spacetime paths which are relevant to gravity are geodesics. Geodesics all have the defining property that their acceleration is zero. So the gravitational field in GR is not an acceleration field. The gravitational field would either be the curvature tensor or the metric tensor, neither of which represent acceleration.

Comment: A metric tensor of uniform acceleration gives the tangent of each geodesic the same magnitude at that event. If you take the collection of all the tangents of the curves at that event, you get a plane. That plane is a specific physical quantity with all the vectors in that plane having the same magnitude but different directions. Same thing with the second derivative. Why can't the plane of accelerations at the event be a physical quantity like a scalar or vector?

Comment: And, secondly, are you going to deny that a gravity fields exists? Place a test object in orbit around the sun. It will have an acceleration that is a property of the manifold created by the energy density of the sun moving through time. How is an acceleration field not the same thing as a gravitational field? How is the gravity field not a property of the curvature of the manifold?

Comment: @TheShepard said "If you take the collection of all the tangents of the curves at that event, you get a plane." I don't think that is true, and certainly I have not seen such a claim justified in the literature.

Comment: @TheShepard said "are you going to deny that a gravity fields exists?" I made no such statement and your making that statement shows that further discussion with you is unlikely to be productive. You make blatant misrepresentations of other people's statements. The bottom line is that a paper is intended to persuade the scientific community, and the reviewer correctly identified that argument as non-persuasive to the community. I am done and will no longer respond to you

Comment: *"If you take the collection of all the tangents of the curves at that event, you get a plane"* That statement was made in the context of geodesics. I don't see how can you deny that all the tangents of all the geodesics at a given event define a plane?

Comment: *"A field is a mapping from events on the manifold to some tensor. Not a mapping from events on a curve to some tensor."* I apologize if you took the question the wrong way, no offense was meant, but you are making the claim here that no acceleration field can be associated with the manifold, only the curve. It would be great if you could address the question: how is a gravitational field different from an acceleration field? Is the gravitational field not an attribute of the manifold?